# Shapeless : Checking of the Type Constraints of Polymorphic Functions (lifted types)

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am writing an internal DSL, and am using Shapeless to enforce type safety. However, I have got stuck with an issue.

The simplified version of the problem is as follows.

Consider the code snippet below:

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.function._
import ops.function._

implicit class Ops[P <: Product, L <: HList](p: P)(implicit val gen: Generic.Aux[P, L]) {
  def ~|>[F, R](f: F)(implicit fp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, L ⇒ R]) =
    f.toProduct(gen.to(p))
}

(1, 2) ~|> ((x: Int, y: Int) ⇒ x + y) // -> at compile time, it ensures the types are aligned.

(1, 2, 3) ~|> ((x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) ⇒ x + y + z) // -> compiles okay

(1, "2", 3) ~|> ((x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) ⇒ x + y + z) // -> gives a compile error, as expected.
```

However, instead of A, I would like to use a container type `Place[A]`.

```
case class Place[A](a: A)

val a = Place[Int](1)
val b = Place[Int]("str")
```

and also ensures the types are aligned with respect to the type parameters.

```
(a, b) ~|> ((x: Int, y: String) ⇒ x.toString + y)
```

That is, in the above case, I would like the types to be checked based on the type parameter of Place[_], which in the above case, `Int` and `String` respectively.

I highly appreciate your help!

Comment: just a hint, since I don't currently have the time to fiddle with it. hlist contraints may help: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/hlistconstraints.scala

Comment: So inside your `Place` your input `P <: Product` type would become `A`? What are you trying to do with the container specifically?

Comment: @flavian, the values are somewhat already lifted in `Place[_]` due to prior computation. In this case, I would like to check that the types are aligned. In addition to that, I am thinking of lifting the functions into containers so that it can be interpreted later (unlike the 1st example).

Comment: @GabrielePetronella, thanks. I will take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a combination of [`Unwrapped`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/commit/f0447aeb7e9ea4622193803e83bb8928c35dc36e) and [`LiftAll`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/39f73305e3cd2746948c6ef2dd1e065fe08cb1e1/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L2831-L2860).

`Unwrapped` lets you extract the content of an `AnyVal`, `LiftAll` summons a given type class for every entry of an `HList`. If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, it could look like the following:

```
case class Place[A](a: A) extends AnyVal // cuz why not?

implicit class Ops[P <: Product, L <: HList, U <: HList, C <: HList](p: P)
  (implicit
    val g: Generic.Aux[P, L],
    val l: LiftAll.Aux[Unwrapped, L, U],
    val c: Comapped.Aux[Place, L, C]
  ) {
    def ~|>[F, R](f: F)(implicit fp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, C ⇒ R]) = {
      def fuckitZip(l1: HList, l2: HList): HList = (l1, l2) match {
        case (h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2) => (h1, h2) :: fuckitZip(l1, l2)
        case _ => HNil
      }
      def fuckitMap(l: HList, f: Any => Any): HList = l match {
        case HNil   => HNil
        case h :: t => f(h) :: fuckitMap(t, f)
      }
      def f(a: Any): Any = a match {
        case (x: Any, y: Any) =>
          x.asInstanceOf[Unwrapped[Any] { type U = Any }].unwrap(y)
      }
      val zp = fuckitZip(g.to(p), l.instances)
      val uw = fuckitMap(zp, f _).asInstanceOf[C]
      f.toProduct(uw)
    }
}
```

Note that here I've used [`Comapped`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/39f73305e3cd2746948c6ef2dd1e065fe08cb1e1/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L84-L105) and an unsafe zip/map to keep it simple, making it typesafe with a proper `HList` zip/map is left as an exercise.

As usually with these complex transformations it might be simpler (and will run/compiler faster) to reimplement everything with a dedicated type class by inlining everything, I just wanted to show that this is doable with primitive operations :)

Comment: Haha this is too funny, and nicely done +100.  You could also typeclass the map with a recursive implicit derivation from HList.